# JMeter with Groovy ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport

Tags: groovy, timer, jmeter, noclassdeffounderror

I created a small Groove script for Timer in JMeter:

```
@Grapes([
@Grab(group = 'joda-time', module = 'joda-time', version = '2.9.2')])

import org.joda.time.*;

dataTime = new DateTime();
if (dataTime.getMinuteOfHour() % 2) {
    1000
} else {
    60000
}
```

In IDE it runs fine.

but in JMeter 2.13 (Groovy Timer) I have got an error:

```
2016/03/09 15:02:52 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:3289)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3287)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:285)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.$getStaticMetaClass(GrapeIvy.groovy)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.<init>(GrapeIvy.groovy:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.getInstance(Grape.java:121)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:159)
    at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getScriptClass(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:374)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:181)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:194)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:166)
    at org.apache.jmeter.timers.JSR223Timer.delay(JSR223Timer.java:42)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.delay(JMeterThread.java:771)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:424)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 5):

I added ivy-2.4.0.jar to lib dir into JMeter directory.

Comment: I fixed mistakes.